# MediaPlayer force close after consecutive clicks

Tags: android, media-player

I've made a button and when you click it, it gives away a short sound(Max one second-sound). But after I've clicked the button about 20 times in a row I get force close.. 
The code is:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.buzzer);
        mp.start();
        }
});
```

I've tried with `mp.stop();` but then my sound stops after it have been played half of the time...

One more thing, does anyone know how to "prepare" the sound when I click? Because the sound gets delayed with some milliseconds the first time I press the button.

Comment: Please show the logcat with the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `MediaPlayer` member variable and initialize it in `onCreate()` the same way you are doing in the listener. Then in the listener just use this code:

```
if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mPlayer.stop();
}
mPlayer.start();
```

Then call `mPlayer.release()` in your `finish()` Activity. My guess is that since none of your MediaPlayer instances are being released, it's running out of memory to use.

The official document for MediaPlayer is actually incredibly descriptive and helpful:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will also look at the android dev site!